# Trying to upload an image S3 via a signedUrl from a browser using fetch but the image is blank in s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My backend is a nodejs application and I want users to upload images to an S3 bucket using an S3 signedUrl.

From my server I am running:

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: bucket }});

app.get('/api/images/signed-url', authMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', 
    { ContentType: 'image/jpeg', Key: uuid() + '.jpeg' }, 
    (_err, url) => res.send({ signedUrl })
})
```

Then from my browser client I upload to that endpoint

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').onchange = async (event) => {
  const { signedUrl } = await fetch('/api/images/signed-url').then(res => res.json())

  const target = event.target
  const file = target.files[0]
  const reader = new FileReader()

  reader.onload = async (event) => {
    event.target.value = null

    await fetch(signedUrl, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: event.target.result,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
      }
    })
  }

  reader.readAsText(file)
}
```

I get a 200 and the image is in S3 however the file in S3 is a tiny 10x10 white box. Can I get some help on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know much js, but `readAsText()` sounds wrong for a binary image. Perhaps use `readAsBinaryString()`?

Answer (score 1):

...almost right, just don't use the filereader, send the blob/file directly in body

```js
  const target = event.target
  const file = target.files[0]

  await fetch(signedUrl, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: file,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    }
  })
```